# Problem with zend framework tutorial of Akrabat

Tags: zend-framework

I have asked this question earlier today but I didn't provide enough information and therefore it was migrated to the serverfault forum.

Well since I think it's not really a server releated problem rather a php related problem i woul lik to ask it here again and ask it properly.

#### My environment

> Xampp installation
>   PHP 5.2.8
>   Windows xp
>   ZF version 1.9.+

#### The problem

As I was going to [this](http://akrabat.com/wp-content/uploads/getting-started-with-zend-framework-163.pdf) tutorial. At a certain point (on page 13 of the pdf) my server crashes.

And I think these are the few lines of code where it goes wrong:
   This is the indexAction of my index controller

```
public function indexAction()
{
    $this->view->title = "My Albums";
    $this->view->headTitle($this->view->title, 'PREPEND');
    $albums = new Model_DbTable_Albums();
    $this->view->albums = $albums->fetchAll();
}
```

If I take away the last line:

```
$this->view->albums = $albums->fetchAll();
```

My site doesn't crash but as soon as i add this line it crashes (apache crashes).

There is no info in the error.log which seems valuebale to me.

Here are the last line of my error log:

http://pastebin.com/m67fdca85

#### Prossibe cause

*I have the idea that it might have something to do with the mysql-pdo  driver but I am not sure.* And I also don't know how to trigger this. All the dll's in my php.ini are enabled and are in the extenstion directory.

Does anyone have an idea how to solve this problem?

I hope I have provided enough info and with enough detail.

Thanks anyway!

Comment: pastebin link doesnt appear to be active

Comment: do a print_r($albums->fetchAll());

see if your connection info is showing in the object info.

Have you got error reporting turned on?

if not trigger that to show all errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So as soon as you fetch that data, your server crashes. Now this means probably that your server crashes on connect. If you're using the PDO_MYSQL Adapter of ZF then the connection is not made before you actually run a query.

Have you conntected to the database on this XAMPP install before in that tutorial with that application or with PDO at all, ever?

Comment: I have connected with the db but never through pdo

Answer (score 1):

i dont see anything in that code that should break the server.
Try and remove Model_DbTable_Albums instance to try and see if its from PDO driver.